# catkin_make android_core SDK directory

Tags: android-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Next troubles for me

ht tp://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Ros%20Development%20Environment

catkin_make @ android directory

i get the error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android_acm_serial'.
> The SDK directory '/opt/android-studio/sdk:/home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.248 secs
make[2]: *** [android_core/CMakeFiles/gradle-android_core] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [android_core/CMakeFiles/gradle-android_core.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

install directory for android studio: `/home/user/opt/android-studio`

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/ros/hydro/bin
:/home/user/catkin_ws_android_core/devel/bin
:/opt/eclipse:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin
:/usr/local/bin
:/usr/sbin
:/usr/bin
:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
:/home/user/catkin_ws/tool_scripts
:/opt/android-studio/sdk/tools
:/opt/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools
:/opt/android-studio/bin
:/home/user/home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk/tools
:/home/user/home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools
:/home/user/home/user/opt/android-studio/bin
:/home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk/tools
:/home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools
:/home/user/opt/android-studio/bin

$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/opt/android-studio/sdk
:/home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk
```

---

Edit:
Thanks to support from gvdhoorn i got a little step further

- installed android tools (adb) from ht tp://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/245-ubuntu-precise-install-android-sdk
- i ve hardcoded the variables `ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH` in `.bashrc` and opend an other terminal (that solved my problem)

java 7 is already installed

`catkin_make` starts running with a lot of warnings

```
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class (junit.swingui.TestSelector$4) that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

and finally fails -> next error:

```
:android_acm_serial:uploadArchives

Uploading: org/ros/android_core/android_acm_serial/0.1.3/android_acm_serial-0.1.3.aar to repository remote at file:///opt/ros/hydro/share/maven
Specified destination directory cannot be created: /opt/ros/hydro/share/maven/org/ros/android_core/android_acm_serial/0.1.3
:android_acm_serial:uploadArchives FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android_acm_serial:uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
> Error deploying artifact 'org.ros.android_core:android_acm_serial:aar': Error deploying artifact: Specified destination directory cannot be created: /opt/ros/hydro/share/maven/org/ros/android_core/android_acm_serial/0.1.3

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6 mins 56.909 secs
make[2]: *** [android_core/CMakeFiles/gradle-android_core] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [android_core/CMakeFiles/gradle-android_core.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

Edit2 :

i deleted Build and Devel

```
catkin_make
```

again

the other projects are uploaded like:

```
Uploading: org/ros/android_core/android_tutorial_teleop/0.1.3/android_tutorial_teleop-0.1.3.apk to repository remote at  file:///home/user/android/devel/share/maven
```

.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Thank you very much gvdhoorn

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188443/catkin_make-android_core-sdk-directory/) by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-31**:
So: what is your question? What did you try yourself, what didn't work and why?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-01**:
I've updated your formatting a bit: use 4 spaces before lines that you want quoted as-is. '&ltcode&gt' doesn't work too well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to some posts on Stack Exchange ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125175/gradle-build-errors-after-updating-android-studio) one and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272127/sdk-location-not-found-android-studio-gradle) one), this can happen with newer versions of Android Studio / gradle / etc.

Apparently adding

```
sdk.dir=/path/to/your/sdk
```

to a file `local.properties` in your project should do the trick.

---

Edit & recap:

1. you have Android Studio in: `/home/user/opt/android-studio`
2. you have set `ANDROID_HOME` to: `/home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk`
3. you have these Studio related directories on your path, in addition to your normal path (all on one line, I just copied your formatting):

   ```
   /home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk/tools:
   /home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools:
   /home/user/opt/android-studio/bin
   ```
4. you can run `adb` in a terminal, and `adb devices` shows you your device (after you've connected it)
5. you have a file called `local.properties` in both `android_core` and the `android_extras` project directories, with the following content:

   ```
   sdk.dir = /home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk
   ```

Correct? If not, please update things to match.

Also, please edit `PATH` and `ANDROID_HOME` to **only** point to the **actual** location of the Android Studio (so `/home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk`), remove the entries that point to `/opt/android-studio`: you don't have it there, so no point in adding those. Also (but minor): your `PATH` includes paths like `/home/user/home/user/opt/android-studio`, remove those.

In a fresh terminal, please make sure the above is all true, remove the `devel` and `build` directories, and try `catkin_make` once more.

> do i really have to unzip the android studio bundle in root/opt?

And no, you don't have to. I have Android Studio under `$HOME/opt` as well, and it works fine.

Additional question: which JDK did you install? I've been using Oracle Java 7u65 successfully.

---

Edit2:

> installed android tools (adb) from ..

That should not have been necessary: `adb` is included in the Android Studio installation. If you've followed proper setup procedure for Android Studio, `adb` should already work.

> I've hardcoded the variables ANDROID_HOME and PATH in .bashrc and opend an other terminal (that solved my problem)

I assumed you had your environment setup properly, but yes, you need these variables to be set in every terminal session you open.

> catkin_make starts running with a lot of warnings

Those warnings are 'fine': it just tells you that some class files in jars distributed with rosjava that have been built with an older version of `javac`. You can ignore these for now.

> and finally fails -> next error

This is a permission error. I don't quite get why it is trying to upload to the maven repo in `/opt/ros/hydro/share`, as I've always understood that it should do that to your `devel` directory in your workspace (at least, that is what it does for me). Is this the only project that does this, do the others get uploaded to your `devel` dir?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on 2014-08-01**:
created a file local.properties with "sdk.dir=/home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk" -- still same error -- "sdk.dir=/opt/android-studio/sdk" -- still same error -- the path in my android sdk manager is "/home/user/opt/android-studio/sdk"

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-01**:
Where did you put the file? It has to go into the gradle project that you are building. And each project needs a copy of it.